# What is the motivation for querying __has_feature(objc_arc)

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm taking a look at some legacy code I need to maintain, and I see many spots where there is the following query:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    // ARC is On
    // ...

#else
    // ARC is Off
    // ...

#endif
```

What could be the motivation for keeping the 'ARC is Off' code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little motivation to keep the no-ARC code in .m files, because you can choose to always compile those with ARC enabled.

In a .h file, you need to keep the no-ARC code if the header file might be imported by a .m file that still uses manual reference counting and the maintainer of that .m file doesn't want to convert the .m file to ARC.